# Delphi Interface inheritance and Observer Pattern

Tags: delphi, exception, observer-pattern

I'd like to create a generic Subject Interface and so reuse it with "specifics" Observer classes. So I tried this code for the Subject:

```
unit uISubject;

interface

type

    ISubject = interface(IInterface)
        procedure RegisterObserver(Observer: IInterface);
        procedure RemoveObserver(Observer: IInterface);
        procedure NotifyObservers;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

And I have the following classes for Observers:

An Observer for serial communication

```
unit uISerialObserver;

interface

type

    ISerialObserver = interface(IInterface)
    ['{EF833BD7-31C1-49B3-8041-F1574AC043F0}']
        procedure DataAvailable(ReceivedData: AnsiString);
    end;

implementation

end.
```

An Observer that update Progress bar

```
unit uIProgressObserver;

interface

type

    IProgressObserver = interface(IInterface)
    ['{05AC7C76-CD41-42AB-B793-1512E68D91D5}']
        procedure UpdateProgressParameters(Min, Max: Cardinal);
        procedure IncrementParameter;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

And I've implemented the Notify method like this:

```
procedure TSerialPortCommunicator.NotifyObservers;
var
    Obs: IInterface;
begin
    for Obs in FObservers do
    begin
        ISerialObserver(Obs).UpdateObserver(FReceivedData);
    end;
end;
```

where

```
FObservers: TList<IInterface>;
```

When `NotifyObservers` runs, Delphi returns an Access Violation Error.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the interface with a dynamic cast using the `as` operator.

Your code, `ISerialObserver(IInterface(Obs))`, is a certain point of failure. You should instead write `Obs as ISerialObserver`. But why not make your list `TList<ISerialObserver>` and thus avoid the cast?

That said, are you sure everything in your list implements `ISerialObserver`? It's not obvious from these excerpts. You can check for interface support with the `is` operator, or the rather more functional `Supports()` function.

Also, you don't need to inherit from IInterface, that is implicit. So you can replace `ISubject = interface(IInterface)` with `ISubject = interface` and so on.

Comment: Thought you were slowing down at 20K? :) +1

Comment: @David: Congratulations on becoming a 'trusted user'; as I said, you would beat me to it!

Comment: Sorry. I commited a mistake in the code and I've edited it. And I'll analyse your suggestion.

Comment: @Najem For interfaces you have to use `as` or `Supports()`. For object instances you can use `TComponent(obj)` but `as` is better because you get a hard runtime error right there and then if it's the wrong type.

Comment: @Ken Gradual wind down.....  @Andreas Thanks. You'll be there soon enough. Trusted user. Nothing left. Jeff had better invent something else to keep us keen!!

Comment: @Najem: either use the `Instance is TMyType` plus `TMyType(Instance)` hardcast, or the `Instance as TMyType` checked cast. The latter if you want to raise an exception for a mismatch; the former if you want to filter out mismatches in a conditional construct like `if/then`.

Comment: check for interface support with the in operator? Is?

Comment: No problem, congrats on the 20k!